# getcomputedstyle object javascript issue

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with the getComputedStyle method. I am trying to get the left and top attributes of an element when clicked.

I am able to access the 'left' attribute, but the 'top' attribute returns an object as opposed to a string.

I loop through the array of elements, attaching two event listeners.
After the click event has fired, when I press the keydown on the target div, I can move from left to right, but up/down does nothing. The style for top returns the window object.

I also have the left and top css declarations defined in the earlier part of the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Object.keys(source_boxes).forEach(function(key){

        source_boxes[key].addEventListener('click',function(){
            clicked = true;
            elem = source_boxes[key];
        });

        document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(clicked == true){
                css = getComputedStyle(elem);

                top =parseInt(css['top']);
                left =parseInt(css['left']);

                if(e.code ==="ArrowUp"){
                    top = top -5;
                    elem.style.top = top +'px';
                }else if(e.code ==="ArrowDown"){
                    top = top +5;
                    elem.style.top = top +'px';
                }else if(e.code ==="ArrowLeft"){
                    left = left -5;
                    elem.style.left = left +'px';
                }else if(e.code ==="ArrowRight"){
                    left = left +5;
                    elem.style.left = left +'px';
                }
            }



        });
    });
```

Comment: You should avoid using implicitly declared global variables. Add `var`, `let` or `const` before your `css`, `top` and `left` variables

Comment: Also, how about debugging the values you get from `css['top']` and `css['left']`?

Comment: Thanks you were correct, I changed the variable naming convention and it seemed to fix it. I had debugged, and the css['top'] kept returning an object for some reason. I changed the variable name and used, per your suggestion, var and it is now working. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` without a `var`, `const` or `let` keyword will map to the implicit global `window.top`, which is [already in use in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) and can't be set.